# Cordova back button override default behavior

Tags: cordova

I've override the Cordova default behavior of the back button so if there any dialogs/modals opens close them (native behavior), but if there is not so i want the default navigation of the back button to be set, what ive tried to just set the window.history.back() but it dosnt seems to be as the default, e.g.: it doesn't close the app if you click on back multi times.

```
      document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(event){
                 if (dialogService.openDialogs.length > 0) {
                     dialogService.closeAll();
                     event.preventDefault();
                 } else {
                     window.history.back();
                 }
         })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you override the default behavior, you should tell the app what to do with this event.
Try this code :

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(event){
  if (dialogService.openDialogs.length > 0) {
     dialogService.closeAll();
     event.preventDefault();
  } else if (document.referrer == "") { //you check that there is nothing left in the history. It will work most of the time in cordova apps but this is not a perfect way to check it    
    navigator.app.exitApp(); //when you override the default behavior, this is the command to close the app
  } else {
     window.history.back();
  }
});
```